# Python jira packapge - Atlassian's bug JRA-41559

Tags: python, python-jira

I get this "Atlassian's but" error after running below code. This same section of code previously worked. Why this is happening? Is this related to JIRA website? Is there a way to overcome? Thanks for helping!

2023-04-23 12:42:42 Atlassian's bug https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-41559

`KeyError: "'issues' : {}"`

code

```
jira_client = JIRA(options={"server": "https://jira.mycompanyname.com/"}, basic_auth=(email, password))
project_name='XXXX'
issues = []
i = 0
chunk_size = 100
while True:
    chunk = jira_client.search_issues(f'project = {project_name}', startAt=i, maxResults=chunk_size,  fields=["id", "fixVersion"])
    i += chunk_size
    issues += chunk.iterable
    if i >= chunk.total: 
        break
```

Restarted Kernel. Didn't solve.